# Stuck with Voice Over

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am making a Thai Braille app (send e-mail, message for blind people) that can write Thai Braille by tapping the screen and matching with Braille letter will show and speak but I am stuck with the Voice Over that change the way of touch.

Is there any way to code Voice Over to use normal touch in the app?

I did this in viewDidLoad but seems doesn't work

UIView *interactionView = [[UIView alloc]init]; [self.view addSubview:interactionView]; [interactionView setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction];

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only on iOS 5 (and later).  A new UIAccessibility API trait, UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction, was added to iOS 5 to disable VoiceOver from handling or changing touches in the specified view or sub view.  Just put your Braille keyboard in a separate UIView, and add something like:

```
[ myBrailleSubView setAccessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction ];
```

That subview will then handle its own touches via it's own touch event delegates.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. :)
(EDIT : prior to iOS 5.0, thanks HotPaw2)

VoiceOver can just be used as a whole : voice synthesis AND specific touch interaction, as stated in [the accessibility programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html)

> "VoiceOver is Apple’s innovative screen-reading technology, which
>   gives users control over their devices without having to see the
>   screen. **VoiceOver does this by acting as an intermediary between an
>   application's user interface and the user's touch**, providing audible
>   descriptions of elements and actions in the application."

Comment: True for iOS 4.x and earlier.